# Measurable with Respect to a Complete Space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:(X, A,\mu) \to [0,\infty]$ have a Lebesgue integral. Show that $f$ is measurable with respect to the completion of the sigma algebra $A$.

I know that I have to show that the pre-image of every subset of $X$ is contained in the completion of $A$, but I'm having trouble figuring out how that follows from the function being Lebesgue integrable. Here's the solution that I've put together:

Suppose $f:(X,A,\mu) \to [0,\infty]$ has a Lebesgue integral. Fix an integrable set E. Then there exists an increasing sequence of simple functions $u_n$ with $u_n\leq f$ and $u_n\to u$. Moreover, $\int_Efd\mu=\lim\int_E u_nd\mu=\int_E\lim u_nd\mu=\int_Eud\mu
\implies\int_E(f-u)d\mu$.

So let g=*f-u*. Take $E_+=\{x\in E:g(x)>0\}$ and $E_-=\{x\in E:g(x)<0\}$. If m($E_+$)>$0$, then there is some closed set K$\subset E_+$ with m(K)>$0$. But

$\int_Kgd\mu=\int_Egd\mu-\int_{E-K}gd\mu=0-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{E_n-K}gd\mu=0$

So it follows that g=$0$ almost everywhere on K, contradicting m(K)>$0$. Thus, m($E_+$)=$0$. Similarly, m($E_-$)=$0$.

$\implies g=0$ almost everywhere $\implies f=u$ almost everywhere. But $u_n$ are measurable by design and therefore u is measurable. Since *f* and *u* differ only on sets of measure $0$, this means that f is measurable not with respect to *A*, but with respect to the completion of *A* with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to math.stackexchange! Around here, we use MathJax/LaTeX to typset mathematics. I fixed your formatting in this question, but for future reference, check here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is your definition of "has a Lebesgue integral"?

Comment: Thanks for the editing tips. By has a Lebesgue integral, I mean that the infimum of the upper Lebesgue sum is equal to the supremum of the lower Lebesgue sum and both have finite value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little something to get you started: There are simple functions $u_n\le f$ and $v_n\ge f$ so that $\int(v_n-u_n)\,d\mu\to0$. Replacing $u_n$ by $u_1\vee u_2\vee\ldots\vee u_n$ and $v_n$ by $v_1\wedge v_w\wedge\ldots\wedge v_n$, you may assume that $u_n$ form an increasing sequence, and $v_n$ a decreasing one. So they both converge pointwise, to limits $u$ and $v$ with $u\le f\le v$. $u$ and $v$ are both measurable (why?), and $u=f=v$ a.e. (again, why?).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I know the measurability of the simple functions follows from their definition which will give us u and v being measurable. I'm not sure I'm convinced that u=f=v almost everywhere, though.

Comment: The difference $v-u$ is nonnegative and has integral zero. It can't have values $>\epsilon$ on a set of positive measure for any $\epsilon>0$. Get it now?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I have one more quick question about your explanation. I understand how the simple functions u_n exist, but I'm not seeing exactly how to show the existence of the simple functions v_n. How do I know for certain that f is bounded?

Comment: There are two approaches to the Lebesgue integral that I know of. The most common tackles the integral of nonnegative functions first, by approximation from below by simple functions. In that approach, you limit attention to measurable functions because that is required to make the theory work. So integrable functions in that approach are measurable *by definition*. I assumed, therefore, that you have been using the other approach, which starts with the integral of bounded functions which are nonzero only on a set of finite measure. …

Comment: … in this other approach, you define integrability by taking upper and lower integrals, as indicated in my answer. But then you need to extend the definition, which my answer did not take into account: You replace $f$ by something like $f_n:=\chi_{E_n\cap F_n} f$ where $E_n=f^{-1}[-n,n]$ and $F_n$ has finite measure, so that $f$ vanishes outside $\bigcup_n F_n$, then take the limit as $n\to\infty$. You then require $f_n$ to integrable for each $n$, so it must be measurable. And then it is not too hard to see that $f$ must be measurable as well, being the limit of $f_n$.

Comment: Ok, my professor defined things in a strange way and that's what's been really tripping me up. I think that I've been able to put together a solution without assuming boundedness that I'll post here. If you could give me feedback on it I'd greatly appreciate it.